# Cannot apply date picker to field on html page added to application using .load

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, event-delegation

I'm attempting to create a single page application which loads in the various pages of my application into a #container using the .load() function in jQuery.

The buttons which load in the pages are being generated dynamically using $.ajax and a $.each loop:

```
$.each(result, function(i, item) {
   $("#menu").append("<li id='"+item.filename+"' class='col-md-12'><span id='"+item.filename+"_link'>" + item.condition_name + "</span></li>");                         
 });
```

On one of my pages I have a form. I want to add a date picker to one of the input fields in the form.

```
<span class="field"><label for="date">Choose Date: </label>
    <input type="date" id="reading_date" name="reading_date" class="date">
</span>
```

I've attempted doing this in jQuery within the click function which loads the page:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "#type1diabetes_link", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load("type1diabetes.html");
    $('.date').datepicker();
});
```

The date picker will not load, no matter what I try and do. I cannot seem to access the .date class. I know the problem has something to do with event delegation, but I just can't seem to get my head around it.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program doesn't wait for `.load()` to finish before running the next line of code. So you call the datepicker function before your content gets updated. According to the jquery documentation, you can add a callback function that runs once `.load()` finishes. This is when you should do the datepicker.

Try this instead:

```
$(document.body).on("click", "#type1diabetes_link", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load("type1diabetes.html", function() {
        $('.date').datepicker();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery's [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead:

```
$("body").delegate("click", "#type1diabetes_link", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#content").load("type1diabetes.html", function() {
        $('.date').datepicker();
   }); 
});
```

I faced this problem when I was loading elements dynamically. More specifically, the binding fails when the element which you trying to access is not present when the DOM loads.